# Using GCC's C++0x mode in production?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

Is anyone using the GCC 4.4.0 [C++0x](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) support in production? I'm thinking about using it with the latest MinGW, but I'm not sure if it's mature enough.

I'm interested in:

- TR1 support
- auto
- initializer lists

Comment: TR1 support should be safe, as it predates C++0x. Auto seems fairly harmless as well. Even if there are bugs in its implementation, they'd most likely manifest as easy-to-fix type errors, rather than bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, TR1 support and `auto` are safe to use.  In the case of `auto` it was one of the first features to be included into the standard and is a relatively small change to the language.  I would therefore have no problem using it.

I would be a bit more hesitant about using `initializer lists`.  On some other forums (eg. comp.lang.c++.moderated) there are questions about their behaviour and its possible that they may change closer to the release of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using GCC 4.4.0 C++0x support in production but I'm using the TR1 features with the help of the Boost Library http://www.boost.org/.

The Boost Library is well tested and often used in production environments. If you convert to the C++0x standard later the only thing you have to do is changing your include Directives http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html.

In my opinion it's currently better to use the Boost Library until the standard is finished. It's a much more compiler independent way.

Answer (score 2):

MinGW simply won't compile with '-std=c++0x'. Strange enough, '-std=gnu++0x' works. Anyway it seems buggy and I won't count on it.

Comment: I'll take a guess - the error is due to missing wide-character functions like vwsprintf, right? That occurs with -std=c++98 or -ansi as well, it's a well known MinGW bug. Nothing C++0x specific.