# Using C++11 in a production environment with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, production-environment

C++11 provides us with a lot of new great and immensly useful tools. [GCC support of C++11](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) has already made good progress. So I have thought about when to switch to C++11. This question relates to gcc only, I do not expect to compile my (our) code with any other compiler.

Would you (did you) switch to C++11 before gcc supports the entire C++11 standard to benefit from the features already implemented? Would you still do this in a production environment where stability and correctness is very important? Do you think it would be a reasonable approach to allow developers only to use certain C++11 features?

How would you (do you) go about deciding when GCCs C++11 support is ready for a production environment?

(Note: I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414897/427532) question, but it specifically relates to gcc 4.4 and is somewhat outdated)

Comment: `auto` and lambdas alone would make me switch. Taking into account that GCC already supports variadic templates (*love*), I'd say, heck yes, switch!

Comment: Definitely yes. Tons of library features are well tested and mature (tuples, hash containers, smart pointers), variadic templates are great, type traits are wonderful... Just don't use the stuff that isn't implemented yet (which you will immediately notice when trying to compile), and there should be no reason to restrict access to this great new language.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I don't think tuples, hash containers or smart pointers are a reason to switch because I can already get them through boost without C++11.

Comment: @GabrielSchreiber: Well, you get them without requiring anyone to carry an additional very large and deeply nested header library around. Sure, there are other ways to get those features.

Comment: We considered switching but GCC 4.6 has so many segfaults (on normal C++03 code compiled with `--stc++0x`) that we decided to wait until a compiler with support makes it into an official RHEL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends.

If it were to power my blog or something like this ? Definitely.

If it were to power a critical service ? Of course not.

I believe that the support of C++11 is too immature as it is now, to be called production ready.

You may settle on a version of gcc, but the truth is that because the successive drafts evolved as new problems were discovered and tackled, the code you write now may well be rejected by a later version, or the behavior may change lightly.

Therefore, I think this judgement truly depends on what you intend to be doing. There is a reason the space shuttle is powered by an old and proven technology: it's a matter of trade-off between ease of development and confidence in the tools.

It's your judgment, you know your situation better than we do.

Answer (score 5):

The GCC C++ developers still think their C++03 support is not up to par, and therefore aren't even setting the __cplusplus version correctly (citation needed, I can look up the bug+discussion). They marked the support as experimental because they started implementing the basics before there was a final draft/standard. By now (ie GCC 4.6), most major flaws have been removed, although some details remain inconsistent with the exact standard wording.

If possible, you should also test with Clang, which IMHO strives and succeeds at better adhering to the puny details in most places where GCC lacks the necessary enforcement. Production use is something that's personal. Me, I think that every compiler has bugs, and although the chance of a bug in the "new stuff" is statistically more probably, chances are you'll also encounter an older bug messing with your  perfectly compliant code. That's why I suggest using at least two compilers to prevent any incompatibilities (or at least reduce them as much as possible).

As for the Standard library, libstdc++ is functional for the most part, but lacking in some large and useful parts like `<regex>`, which is sad. If you're feeling lucky, you should be able to get LLVM's [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) working on at least Linux and Mac, this is a feature complete c++11 library minus `<atomic>`), but also the "new kid on the block".

To summarize: the more compilers and Standard libraries you run your code against the better (although you should check which ones are correct, and which are buggy). This inevitably reduces the amount of C++11 features available to you, although if you go with GCC/Clang, only lambda's, uniform initializers and `<atomic>` fall outside your scope. MSVC is a different story...

Comment: The incorrectly set `__cplusplus` is a bug, not due to lack of confidence. I saw a Bugzilla ticket a while back which basically confirms that abuse of the symbol within the library and on platforms (I recall that Sun was mentioned) has locked them into defining it as `1`, at least for now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Note on `__cplusplus`, it was indeed done for Sun, and it is solved in recent versions of gcc (4.7+ I think).